# How to get rid of the secound scrollbar?

Tags: css, scroll, double, scrollbar

Hi i have made my portfolio but cannot get rid of a double scroll bar which appears when clicking on one of the portfolio items.

I have tried all the overflow hidden and locked, but nothing has been working. When i put overflow to hidden the scroll function disappears..

www.krisjanismezulis.com/v2/test4.html

`#pageslide {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 999999`

Answer (score 1):

## pageslide in http://www.krisjanismezulis.com/v2/css/jquery.pageslide.css

replace

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

with

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: when i replace scroll with hidden than the page locks, and it is no more possible to scroll...

Answer (score 0):

When the portfolio item is opened, you have to set the the `body` to `overflow:hidden`. That'll get rid of your double-scrollbar issue.

Remember that when the portfolio item is closed, you have to reset the overflow on `body` back to `overflow:auto`

Comment: thank you for the answer, i completely understand what you mean, but how do i do this practically?  Do i need to create a jquery action or something like that that trigers the overflow,if yes than how?

Comment: Whatever function that handles the portfolio item open you'd also perform `$("body").css("overflow","hidden");` and the function that handles the portfolio close button you'd also perform `$("body").css("overflow","auto");`